# Generic overload at compile-time

Tags: java

Its possbile, to design a way to call different method-overloads at compile-time?

Lets say, I have this little class:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BaseValidator<T> {
    private final T newValue;
}
```

Now, I need methods that returns diffrent Objects (depends on the `T`).
Like this:

```
private StringValidator getValidator() {
    return new ValidationString(newValue);
}

private IntegerValidator getValidator() {
    return new Validation(newValue);
}
```

At the end, I want a call-hierachy that is very fluent and looks like this:

```
new BaseValidator("string")
    .getValidator() // which returns now at compile-time a StringValidator
    .checkIsNotEmpty();
//or
new BaseValidator(43)
    .getValidator() // which returns now a IntegerValidator
    .checkIsBiggerThan(42);
```

And in my "real"-case (I have a very specific way to update objects and a lot of conditions for every object and the chance of a copy-and-paste issue is very high. So the wizard enforces all developer to implement exact this way.) :
[image: Ide Image]

I tried diffrent ways. Complex generics inside the Validators, or play around with the generics. My last approch looks like this.

```
public <C> C getValidator() {
    return (C) getValidation(newValue);
}

private ValidationString getValidation(String newValue) {
    return new StringValidator(newValue);
}

private ValidationInteger getValidation(Integer newValue) {
    return new IntegerValidation(newValue);
}
```

What is the trick?

//edit: I want it at compile-time and not with `instanceof`-checks at runtime.

Comment: Create a separate builder class for this

Comment: Don't forget that the return type is not part of the method signature, thus you can't overload a method by changing the return type. Regarding your question: I as a developer who wants to use your validators wouldn't start with `new BaseValidator()` and then hope that `getValidator()` would  return what I need. I would use the correct validator directly (i.e. `new ValidationString("someString").myValidationmethod()`).

Comment: The base-class have to be generic. In my case, the base-class is a large wizard. (See https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/wizard-design-pattern.html)

Comment: if the functions you call ask for different parameter types, why don't just implement the methods within the same class? The compile-time variance will be given by the function that is being called

Comment: @user6537157 this "wizard" design pattern is pretty much just the builder but made more confusing to work with. It solves a problem nobody should actually have by front-loading all your business validation into your code. Change the business rules and now you have to change EVERY. SINGLE. OBJECT. INSTANTIATION.

Comment: the best solution is to use `new StringValidator()` or `new IntegerValidation()` directly. This is the shortest, most clear and most reliable approach.

Comment: I added a image, why this is not that what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to add more class-steps. You can go a the generic way or a way with explict types (in this examples, `String`). Our requirement for all updates-methods (we have many database-objects ...) are a little complicated. We want only one update-method (for each db-object), which ...

1. Ignore fields, that are null.
2. Ignore field, that are equal to "old" value.
3. Validate not ignored fields.
4. Save only, when no validation-issues occur.

To do that with many if-blocks is possbile but not really readable. And copy-paste-fails haves a high probably.

Our code look like this:

```
private void update(@NonNull final User.UpdateFinalStep params) {

    UpdateWizard.update(dbUserService.get(params.getId())

            .field(params.getStatus())
            .withGetter(DbUser::getAccountStatus)
            .withSetter(DbUser::setAccountStatus)
            .finishField()

            .field(Optional.ofNullable(params.getUsername())
               .map(String::toLowerCase)
               .orElse(null))
            .withGetter(DbUser::getUsername)
            .withSetter(DbUser::setUsername)
            .beginValidationOfField(FieldName.USERNAME)
            .notEmptyAndMatchPattern(USERNAME_PATTERN, () -> this.checkUniqueUsername(params.getUsername(), params.getId()))
            .endValidation()

            .field(params.getLastName())
            .withGetter(DbUser::getLastname)
            .withSetter(DbUser::setLastname)
            .beginValidationOfField(FieldName.USER_LASTNAME)
            .notEmptyAndMatchPattern(LAST_NAME_PATTERN)
            .endValidation()

            .field(params.getFirstName())
            .withGetter(DbUser::getFirstname)
            .withSetter(DbUser::setFirstname)
            .beginValidationOfField(FieldName.USER_FIRSTNAME)
            .notEmptyAndMatchPattern(FIRST_NAME_PATTERN)
            .endValidation()

            .save(dbUserService::save);
}
```

This is very readable and allows to add new field in a very simple way. With the generics, we dont give the "stupid developer" a chance to do an misstake.

As you can see in the image, accountStatus and username points to different classes.
[image: Intellj Image]

At the end, we can use in a very fluent way the update-method:

```
userService.startUpdate()
   .withId(currentUserId)
   .setStatus(AccountStatus.INACTIVE)
   .finallyUpdate();
```

Answer (score 4):

> What is the trick?

Not to do it like this.

Provide static factory methods:

```
class BaseValidator<T> {
  static ValidationString getValidation(String newValue) {
    return new ValidationString(newValue);
  }

  static ValidationInteger getValidation(Integer newValue) {
    return new ValidationInteger(newValue);
  }
}

class ValidationString extends BaseValidator<String> { ... }
class ValidationInteger extends BaseValidator<Integer> { ... }
```

Although I consider this to be odd: you are referring to subclasses inside the base class. Such cyclical dependencies make the code hard to work with, especially when it comes to refactoring, but also perhaps in initialization.

Instead, I would suggest creating a utility class to contain the factory methods:

```
class Validators {
  private Validators() {}

  static ValidationString getValidation(String newValue) {
    return new ValidationString(newValue);
  }

  static ValidationInteger getValidation(Integer newValue) {
    return new ValidationInteger(newValue);
  }
}
```

which has no such cycles.

---

A really important thing to realize about generics is that it is nothing more than making explicit casts implicit (and then checking that all of these implicit casts are type-safe).

In other words, this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("foo");
System.out.println(list.get(0).length());
```

is just a nicer way of writing:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add((String) "foo");
System.out.println(((String) list.get(0)).length());
```

Whilst `<String>` looks like it is part of the type, it is basically just an instruction to the compiler to squirt in a load of casts.

Generic classes with different type parameters  all have the same methods. This is the specific difficulty in your approach: you can't make the `BaseValidator<String>.getValidator()` return something with a `checkIsNotEmpty` method (only), and the `BaseValidator<Integer>.getValidator()` return something with a `checkIsGreaterThan` method (only).

Well, this isn't quite true to say you *can't*. With your attempt involving the method-scoped type variable (`<C> C getValidator()`), you can write:

```
new BaseValidator<>("string").<StringValidator>getValidator().checkIsNotEmpty()
```

(assuming `StringValidator` has the `checkIsNotEmpty` method on it)

But:

- Let's not mince words: it is ugly.
- Worse than being ugly, it isn't type safe. You can equally write:

  new BaseValidator<>("string").getValidator().checkIsGreaterThan(42)

  which is nonsensical, but allowed by the compiler. The problem is that the return type is chosen at the call site: you will either have to return null (and get a `NullPointerException` when you try to invoke the following method); or return some non-null value and risk a `ClassCastException`. Either way: not good.

What you can do, however, is to make a generic validator a parameter of the method call. For example:

```
interface Validator<T> {
  void validate(T b);
}

class BaseValidator<T> {
  BaseValidator<T> validate(Validator<T> v) {
    v.validate(this.value);
  }
}
```

And invoke like so, demonstrating how you can chain method calls to apply multiple validations:

```
new BaseValidator<>("")
    .validate(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .validate(s -> s.matches("pattern"))
    ...

new BaseValidator<>(123)
    .validate(v -> v >= 0)
    ...
```

Comment: For my case not a option.

Comment: I added a image, why this is not that what I want.

Comment: "It's not an option" and "I can't make it work" are the very key things here. The wizard design pattern is plain bad - it only looks good when presented but you end up with exactly problems like the one you face right now. Moreover, that's before even you have to maintain it. Adding a new "step" of validation will make code across your entire database invalid. It's not easy to change, it's not in any way concise, it's not solving any problem you couldn't solve by using traditional design patterns.

Comment: A new step for validation can be added very easy. Each validate-method will return the "validation"-step itself until `.endValidation` called. And it solves some requirements in very nice and readble way. Its offtopic, but we can discuss this in private chat.